# get max record in table

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have table like this:

#### table school

```
ID_School     name
--------------------
ACH001        jack
ACH001        gon
ACH001        fanny
ACH001        tony
ACH002        vera
ACH002        jessica
ACH003        rey
ACH003        tomy
```

I want output the max record ID_School in this table, and the output like this :

```
ID_School  count
-----------------
ACH001     4
```

Comment: This is not clear. Do you want the school and count of the school that has the most students? (And should you have the homework tag?)

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

`select ID_school,count(ID_school) as total from school group by names order by total desc limit 1;`

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL:

```
select top 1 ID_School, count(*) IdCount
from school
group by ID_School
order by IdCount desc
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle:

```
SELECT id_school, cnt
  FROM (SELECT id_school, count(*) cnt
          FROM school
         GROUP BY id_school
         ORDER BY cnt)
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```